# Игнорирование escape последовательности в fmt.Print()

Tags: golang

Столкнулся с тем что в функции
    fmt.Print("12\b3")
не срабатывает последовательность \b

получаю 123

ожидаю 13

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эта последовательность для терминала и то не для всякого.

Comment: Для контролирования терминала вам понадобится что-то типа [termbox-go](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go).

Comment: Понял. Попробую termBox. Спасибо.